# Filtering user interviews using text response in Python

Tags: python, pandas, sentiment-analysis, topic-modeling

I am analyzing a large data set of user interviews and am using topic modeling as well as sentiment analysis. To make this more useful, I am filtering by text responses, for example looking at individuals who have been with the entity for longer than 18 months vs. less than 18 months.

The input is an Excel file that contains 35 tabs, each sheet being the exact same template. The columns being interview topic, interview question, and interview responses. The data follows this format with all responses contained within the interview responses column.

| INTERVIEW QUESTIONS |  | INTERVIEW RESPONSES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Introduction | What is your role? (i.e., program manager, senior program manager, program director?) |  |
|  | What department do you work for? |  |
|  | How long have you worked for the City? |  |
|  | What projects are you working on? |  |

Filtering is done by grabbing a text response from the interviews. All interview responses are recorded in an Excel template for easy integration with Python.

This is what I am using currently, but I feel like there has to be an easier way to accomplish this filtering. The count is simply for error checking as the code is running through the sheets.

The output I am aiming for is an updated dataframe that only contains responses from departmental PMs.

```
#Filtering Based On Departmental PM role

count = 0

df_departmental = pd.DataFrame()


for sheet in sheets:
  df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet)
  df.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 1': 'Questions', 'INTERVIEW QUESTIONS': 'Question Topics', 'INTERVIEW RESPONSES': 'Interview Responses'}, inplace=True)

  df['Interview Responses'] = df['Interview Responses'].astype(str)
  check = df['Interview Responses'].loc[1]

  if check == 'Departmental PM':

    df['Clean_Responses'] = df['Interview Responses'].apply(lambda x: finalpreprocess(x))
    df['Clean_Responses'] = df['Clean_Responses'].str.replace('^[0-9]','')
    df['Sentiment_Rating'] = df['Clean_Responses'].apply(lambda x: sentiment_score(x))
    df_departmental = df_departmental.append(df)

    count += 1
    print(count)
```

Comment: It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing any of your data and your expected output. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Where is your data and where is your expected output?  You say you are filter9ing on 'Departmental PM' but you fail to define where this is located within your dataframe.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry about that. This is all done in a Collab notebook and the data is loaded in every time my instance is started.

All text that is being analyzed is located in the Interview Repsonses column.

Comment: Telling us the data is loaded every time your instance is created doesn't show 8s what the data looks like. Please supply the expected [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example"). We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points. This allows testing suggestions against your data and desired output.

Comment: Done :) Let me know if you need more info.